# How to match system date with the date from database mysql

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a database named work created using mysql in which a table named register is created. It contain a column renewdate. I accessed the table from java swing like this

```
    conn=ConnectionDB.conn();
    Date d=sysdate();
    String sql="select renewdate from register";
    try
    {
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        Date dates;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            dates = rs.getDate("renewdate");
            System.out.println(dates);
            if(dates==d)
            {
               SendMailTLS.sendMail();
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is to send an email when renewdate equals system date. I generate current date using function sysdate() and assigned it to d. Also assigned renewdate in table to dates using dates = rs.getDate("renewdate"). 
My problem is I can not match up both d and dates and thus can not sent email. Could you help me how to match d and dates. 
I tried while(rs.next()) all the dates from table register is obtained. But can not match with d using if(dates==d). Also I tried if(rs.next()), but it only fetch first renewdate from table. So how could i check all the values of renewdate and match with the current date to sent message

Comment: did you check your database date format is same as sysdate()?

Comment: What `Date` class are you using for your variable `d` - `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`? Maybe also show us the `sysdate` method. Do you expect dates only (without time information)?

Comment: Don't ever compare the value of two objects using == operator. What you are doing is checking, if the two pointers point to the same object. Even if two objects have the same value it doesn't mean, that they are the same objects. Use methods like compareTo() or equals().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change a query string to

```
// NOW() in mysql will get the current date and time. So here you get only renewdates matched with current date and time
String sql="select renewdate from register where renewdate = NOW()";

// If you want to compare only with date not time, then go with 
String sql="select renewdate from register where renewdate = CURDATE()";
```

There is no need for this `if(dates == d)` in your above code. Send mail as soon you have next element in your `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Nice code! So:

Save the value of date into strings like:

```
Date   d=sysdate();
String strDate1 = d.toString();
String strDate2 = rs.getDate("renewdate").toString;
```

Then compare it like:

```
strDate1.equals(strDate2);
```

as Strings contain references to "words", not the "words" themself, the == opereator would do something else;

Couly you please send us your whole code for this app anyway, as it would be a nice peace of work to learn from?

Comment: I created a swing page with netbeans. So there is lot of system generated code. Which part you interested in?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in code, here is a way:-

Convert date fetched from database into java.util.Date object using below code (assuming date is stored in GMT):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date dateInDB = formatter.parse(dates);
```

Then, you can simply use `java.util.Date` `equals` method to compare `d` with `dateInDB`.

If you want to ignore time portion while comparing two dates, call below method (that sets time portion to 00:00:00) for each date and use returned date in `equals` method:

```
public static Date getZeroTimeDate(Date dateWithTime) {
    Date res = dateWithTime;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime( dateWithTime );
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    res = calendar.getTime();

    return res;
}
```

This way it does not uses any deprecated method too.

Hope this helps!